# Почему функция JSON_ARRAYAGG возвращает не уникальные значения в JSON массив?

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle19c, oracle18c

Пытаюсь поместить результат одноколоночного запроса в массив JSON, чтобы его использовать на веб-сервере.

Пробую как-то так:

```
SELECT col FROM tbl
/       
COL
---
A
C
A
B

SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
  'ArrayKey' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG( col ) 
) AS jsonResult
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT col as col
       FROM tbl);

JSONRESULT
--------------------------------
{"ArrayKey":["A","C","A","B"]}
```

Этот запрос возвращает в результате массив, который содержит все значения из столбца, т.е. игнорирует `DISTINCT` в подзапросе.  Без выражения `JSON_ARRAYAGG` результат уникален:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col as col FROM tbl
/
COL
---
B
C
A
```

Пытался также поместить `DISTINCT` внутрь `JSON_ARRAYAGG`, но результат тот же:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT (
  'ArrayKey' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(DISTINCT col) 
) AS jsonResult
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT col AS col FROM tbl);
```

Что не так в моем коде? Из-за чего массив выводит все значения, а не отдельные?

На [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7faaed8fd64e897a2129683db992d6f9).

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to return distinct values in a JSON_ARRAYAGG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55736219/6571020) от участника [@jwas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11268755/jwas)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/55736219/6571020

Answer (score 3):

Похоже на баг в выпуске 18c. В версии 19.3.0 больше не воспроизводится:

```
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

SQL> SELECT JSON_OBJECT (
  2    'ArrayKey' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(col)
  3  ) AS jsonResult
  4  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT col as col FROM tbl);

JSONRESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"ArrayKey":["B","C","A"]}
```

Для тех, у кого 18c, в качестве обходного пути можно воспользоваться `GROUP BY` вместо `DISTINCT`. Участник [@sticky bit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55736588) в принятом ответе предложил использовать подсказку `NO_MERGE` на подзапрос, или CTE с подсказкой `MATERIALIZE`.

Все варианты рабочих запросов на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d66e09ffab0b20a620345b41b381b0c1):

```
select json_object ('ArrayKey' value json_arrayagg (col order by col)) jsonResult
from (select col from tbl group by col)
/
SELECT /*+NO_MERGE(x)*/ json_object(
     'ArrayKey' VALUE json_arrayagg(col)) jsonResult
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT col FROM tbl) x
/
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT /*+MATERIALIZE*/ DISTINCT col
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT json_object(
    'ArrayKey' VALUE json_arrayagg(col)) jsonResult
FROM cte
/
```

---

Участник [@Beda Hammerschmidt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64506930/6571020) в ответе упомянул баг:

> Bug 27757725 - JSON GENERATION AGGREGATION FUNCTIONS IGNORE DISTINCT

Но бльше информации по нему не предоставил.